Setting CpoParameters in docplex CpoCallback does not take effect
When using cplex for modeling and solving, it is desired to reset the solving parameter TimeLimit in the callBack function of cplex. In Java, using cplex for modeling can take effect, but in Python, using docpelx for modeling CpoCallback, the parameter modification is successful, but it does not take effect during solving. Why does this happen? Is it because Python already passed the solved parameters to the underlying C++before solving, so that subsequent modifications do not work? Is there any solution?python cpoCallback code java cpoCallback code
According to logic, setting TimeLimit in CpoCallback in Java works. It should also work if implemented in Python, but it doesn't work now

What does this question have to do with the Unix command cp?  Removing the cp tag.

This is a current limitation of the Python API.
As a workaround, you could stop the search in the callback when your conditions are met, and launch another search with the updated limit.
for instance, you could have in the invoke() function something like:
if event == docplex.cp.solver.cpo_callback.EVENT_SOLUTION: 
  solver.abort_search()


Thank you for your answer, but this method requires two searches each time, although the first search time is shorter. Is there a way to use only one search, and manually end it with "solver.abort_search()" to get the existing solution?

The limits of the search cannot be changed with docplex.cp currently, so you will need either to use the C++, .net or Java API, or, if keeping Python, to launch a second search with the new limits. To improve efficiency, you can store the solution found by the first search, and use set_starting_point to reinject it in the second search.

Thank you for your answer. Our current project must be completed in Python. The current problem is that since our project is a CP model, it is difficult to find an optimal solution, so we need to set a timeLimit to stop it at a specified time. However, this set timeLimit includes the time of (engine + extraction), and we want to set only the engine time. Therefore, when the model is relatively large, the extraction may not be completed before the timeLimit we set, and the engine will not solve it.

I tried to use solver.abort_search() to stop it when our timeLimit is met, but there is no solution in the returned result. Does the set_starting_point method you mentioned require this solution?

btw， when the model is relatively large (150,000 variables, 620,600        constraints), cp.solve() reports an error "0SError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument" or BrokenPipeError  in self.pout.write(frame) in the _write_message(self, cid, data=None) method. Do you know what the problem is?

As for set_starting_point: yes it is expected to have a (possibly partial) solution as parameter, see https://ibmdecisionoptimization.github.io/docplex-doc/cp/docplex.cp.model.py.html#docplex.cp.model.CpoModel.set_starting_point

But set_starting_point does not seem to match your needs. In your case, you could launch a solve without specifying any time limit and handle "manually" the time limit: add a callback that watches the "EndExtraction" events and the "Periodic" events. Its invoke() method, at an endExtraction event, stores the current time, and at a Periodic event stops the search if the elapsed time reaches your time limit.

For the OSError, you already have open another thread.

Thank you very much for your answer. We also tried this approach that watches the "EndExtraction" events and the "Periodic" events before. But when we call "solver.abort_search()" to end the search, the result returned by "cp.solve()" does not contain a Solution. Our biggest problem now is how to get the current Solution after we manually stop the search with "solver.abort_search()".
